# grid.arrange and list of ggplots in R markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, gridextra

````
Here is my code

   
    ---
title: "Test_markdown"
author: 
date: 
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r libraries, echo = F}
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
```

```{r plots, echo = F}
my_df <- data.frame(Date_clmn = c(as.Date("2020-07-23"), 
                                  as.Date("2020-07-22"),
                                  as.Date("2020-07-21")),
                    val_clmn = c(1,2,4))

list_ggplot_obj <- list()
for (el in seq(1,15)){
  my_df$val_clmn = my_df$val_clmn*el
  ggplot_obj <-ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = Date_clmn, y=val_clmn )) + geom_line()
  list_ggplot_obj[[el]] <- ggplot_obj
}

do.call("grid.arrange", c(list_ggplot_obj, ncol=2))

```
````

Here is how output looks:[image: squished]

With `el in seq(1,5)` it looks fine, but how do I resize it with values greater than 15?

Comment: A bit better description of your actual problem might be convenient. Is this representable? Are the axis the same in all plots? Eg. could you combine the plots to have the same axis and instead split it using `facet_wrap`?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you, using `patchwork`. I took your code for plots and the result is better. Then you can adjust in `rmarkdown` with `out.width`, `fig.height`, and `fig.width` parameters.

```
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
my_df <- data.frame(Date_clmn = c(as.Date("2020-07-23"), 
                                  as.Date("2020-07-22"),
                                  as.Date("2020-07-21")),
                    val_clmn = c(1,2,4))

list_ggplot_obj <- list()
for (el in seq(1,15)){
  my_df$val_clmn = my_df$val_clmn*el
  ggplot_obj <-ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = Date_clmn, y=val_clmn )) + geom_line()
  list_ggplot_obj[[el]] <- ggplot_obj
}
#Plot
wrap_plots(list_ggplot_obj,ncol = 2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is definitely improvement over mine, but still a bit far away from nice formatting. I do not understand why if I plot only 5 graphs it looks fine, but with 15 it looks bad?

Comment: @user1700890 It is because of `rmarkdown` space. Try increasing `out.width` to `out.width=500%` and play with height and width. After that your plots will fit perfectly despite how long they are !